# SQL: Bars which every drinker frequents (Using NOT EXISTS)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to learn how to use `NOT EXISTS` correctly and the logic that goes behind it. I have this query:

> Bars which every drinker frequents

Along with this `frequents` table:

[image]

Just from looking at the table, I know `Blue Angel` should be the result. I started with something like this (this doesn't give me what I want):

```
SELECT f.bar 
FROM frequents f 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ff.drinker 
    FROM frequents ff 
    WHERE f.drinker <> ff.drinker 
        AND f.bar = ff.bar
);
```

So if `f.bar` is "A.P. Stump's", I have to check if every other name in the table also frequents "A.P. Stump's". I can't seem to figure out how to do that.

What would I have to do? Please note, I HAVE TO use `NOT EXISTS` in my query.

Comment: _I HAVE TO use NOT EXISTS in my query_ We are not supposed to do your homework for you. Lecture's look at this site too.

Comment: I understand. I wasn't looking for an answer but more of a guide on how I should proceed as I am having a hard time understanding the logic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using `group by` and `having`:

```
select bar
from frequents b
group by bar
having count(*) = (select count(distinct drinker) from frequents);
```

This query simply counts the number of drinkers in each bar.  If the count matches the total number of drinkers, then the "bar" passes and is in the result set.

This assumes that the `frequents` table doesn't have duplicate rows for `bar`/`drinker`.  If so, use `count(distinct drinker)` instead of `count(*)`.

Although this can be phrased as a `NOT EXISTS` query (actually, two `NOT EXISTS` would be in the query), I find no use in actually doing it that way.  The nested `NOT EXISTS` is an interesting thought exercise, if you are learning SQL.  Aggregation is much more flexible and can answer a much broader range of problems (say, how many bars are frequented by *most* of the drinkers).